# Pytorch - predict multiple parameters in neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I have two parameters which I want a neural network to predict. What is the best or most conventional method to implement the loss function? Currently I just define the loss, `torch.nn.L1Loss()`, which automatically computes the mean for both parameters such that it becomes a scalar.

Another plausible method would be to create two loss functions, one for each parameter, and successively backpropagate.

I don't really see whether both methods compute the same thing and whether one method is better (or plain wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The probelm could be seen as a Multi-task Probelm. For example, two parameters represents A-Task and B-Task respectively.

In Multi-task, two loss function is often used.

The usual form is as follows,

$$total_loss = \alpha * A_losss(\hat{y_1},y_1) + \bata * A_losss(\hat{y_2},y_2)$$

The $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the weight of the loss function.Usually they are both 1 or 0.5.